# Local Notification iPhone sdk

Tags: ios4

How can I change the text of buttons on alert  of a local notification. By Default it is  "Close" and "View". I have to replace it with "YES" and "NO". 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the 'View' button by providing a string in the UILocalNotification's *alertAction* property. I don't think you get a choice for the Close button.

Comment: Thanks Caleb.But is there any way to customize Close button too?

Comment: As I said, I don't think there is. At least, I don't see it in the docs, and I don't think I've seen any apps that rename that button.